# vform multiselected dropdown default selected and expected an array error

Tags: vue.js

**Can anyone help me I used Vform When I clicked edit button then it's show this error that expect array but I used already array in categories[] and also how to selected default category ?**

I used vform and axios. I want to make a post with multiple category it's store successfully but when I click edit button then I get error that it's expected an array but I bind it an array and also how I make default select when it's edit mode ?

```
<form @submit.prevent="editMode ? updateVal() : createVal()">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Category</label>
          <select class="form-control"
            multiple
            v-model="form.categories"
            name="categories[]"
            :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('categories') }">
            <option v-for="catetoryValue in getCategory" :key="catetoryValue.id" :value="catetoryValue.id">{{ catetoryValue.name }}</option>
          </select>
          <has-error :form="form" field="categories"></has-error>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button v-show="editMode" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <button v-show="!editMode" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false,
      categories:[],
      selected: null,
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        title: "",
        categories:[],
      })
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getCategory(){
    if (this.$gate.isAdminOrAuthor()) {
        axios
          .get("api/getcategory")
          .then((response) => {
              this.getCategory = response.data
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log("Error...");
          });
      }
    },
    newModal() {
      this.editMode = false;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addnewmodal").modal("show");
    },
    edidModal(value) {
      this.editMode = true;
      this.form.reset();
      $("#addnewmodal").modal("show");
      this.form.fill(value);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getCategory();
  },
};
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the Form class constuctor? You haven't showed it.

Comment: can you please check the form now ?

Comment: I asked about this: `form: new Form({
        id: "",
        title: "",
        categories:[],
      })`. What is `Form` in this code? You don't import it, it is not defined in this code. What does the definition of this class look like?

Comment: I install this form using npm this form I used vform in github and initial this form in my app.js file like 

`import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'`

`window.Form = Form;`

here is form link in github 

https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform

Comment: I looked at the docs in the link - there's not a single example of an array passed to this Form constuctor, just strings or nulls. So unless you know that it is possible to do that, I suspect this is your problem. Try logging `this.form` value and check if it has a `categories` property and if yes, what type is it.